# How can I import SQLDeveloper connections into Toad?

Tags: database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

I have exported some database connections from SQL Developer into an XML connection file. Is it possible to import those connections into Toad 11.6? When I attempt to use the XML file to do so, Toad replies with this error:

> The passwords in the import file appear to have been encrypted by a
> user different from the current user and will not be imported

How can I import SQLDeveloper connections into Toad?

Comment: Kindly Go through [How to ask questions on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & Edit necessary changes to your question.

Comment: @LuFFy - the question makes sense to me although it could benefit from some capitalization and punctuation tweaks!

Comment: @LuFFy - I would definitely consider your suggestion. I was in a bit hurry. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer... No, this is not possible with 11.6.

Toad 12.9 and newer does support import from SQL Developer connections XML file, but your passwords will not be imported. Toad encrypts passwords using AES and its own key. I suspect SQL Developer does something similar to protect that data. It wouldn't be very secure if Toad could decrypt another tool's encrypted passwords and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Michael S